# How to add 5 images in one row in bootstrap 3.0 without any gap using col-md-*

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want add 5 images without any gap using col-md-* in bootstrap 3.0. bootstrap has 12 grids. but i put only 5 images. how to do it.. ?

Comment: Put all five images into one col-12 column. Or add your own class, that makes columns take 20% width (plus whatever you want it to be when the tablet/mobile breakpoints are reached.)

Answer (score 0):

You just answered your own question, with bootstrap's col-md-* you cannot do it without any gaps. Since there are 12 columns, and you want 5 images to show, there will be 2 columns left.

Either put 6 images (I guess you don't want that), or change col-md-2 css rule to have width 20% (which I do not recommend), or create your own css rule that will have float: left, width: 20% (I recommend this one) but with other css rules for different widths of the screen (depending on your needs).

Answer (score 0):

First of all sorry. Didn't knew posting links and tutorials are not allowed.
Now i belive i kinda solved your problem.
I created a grid for 5 columns. They collapse into 100% width at 800px (you can change it easily).

```css
.grid-container{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.grid-row {
    margin-left: inherit;
    margin-right: inherit;
}
/*-- our cleafix hack -- */
.grid-row:before,
.grid-row:after {
    content:"";
    display: table ;
    clear:both;
}


.col-1{ width: 20%;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
.col-offset-1 {
     margin-left: 20%;
     float: left;
     padding: 5px;

 }
.col-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 40%;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
.col-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 60%;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
.col-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 80%;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}


@media all and (max-width:800px){
    .col-1 { width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: auto;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .grid-container {
        width: 100%;
    }
    img {
        display: block;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

}
img {
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-row">
        <div class="col-offset-2 col-1"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x150" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-1"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x150" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I don't really know if that's what you've been looking for.